# equals() method is not working with string

Tags: java

I have a string

```
number="(1234)5678";
```

But the if block is not executed:

```
if("(".equals(number.charAt(0)))
{
   System.out.println("IFFF");
}
else
{
   System.out.println("OUT");
}
```

How do I change the boolean expression to execute the if block?

Comment: in your case you could use the `startsWith()` method of `String` which might be easier to understand, what you are doing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following code:

```
if(number.startsWith("(", 0))
    {
      System.out.println("IFFF");
    }
    else
    {         
      System.out.println("OUT");
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

`charAt()` returns a `char`. Comparing `char` and `String` with `.equals()` will always return `false`.

You'll need

```
 if('(' == number.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because `charAt(..)` returns `char` not `String`. And one of if-clauses in `equals` in String class is:

```
   if (anObject instanceof String) {
   ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put: if(number.charAt(0)=='(')

Answer (score 0):

The  charAt() function always returns char..equals() is used for comparing strings.

Characters are primitives, you can compare them with the "==" operator.

```
 String number="(1234)5678";
    if('(' == number.charAt(0))
              {
                  System.out.println("IFFF");
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println("OUT");
              }
```